# Comment after \fbox{ changes its width

Tags: boxes, xy-pic, linguistics, comments

Below are two schemes I did with `xyling` (which I understand builds on `xypic`, hence the tag); they are identical except for the labelling and one arrow being dashed in the lower one. They are also identical in width.

Now if I move the comment in line 6 to line 7 (so that line 7 then reads `\fbox{%GB-Theory`), then this `fbox`'s width will be slightly reduced. Same thing goes for the comment in line 14 and `fbox{` in line 15. I put the comment right after `{` and the width will be slightly reduced. I have no idea why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xyling}
\date{}
\begin{document}

%GB-Theory
\fbox{
\Treek[.5]{3}{
       & \K{D-Structure}\AR{d} \\
       & \K{S-Structure} \AR{dl}\AR{dr}\\
\K{LF} & & \K{PF} }
}

%Minimalism
\fbox{
\Treek[.5]{3}{
       & \K{\textsc{numeration}}\AR{d} \\
       & \K{\textsc{spellout}} \AR{dl}\ARdash{dr}\\
\K{LF} & & \K{PF} }
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A newline is a space. If you comment it out, you remove the space from the list of tokens TeX parses.

Comment: In addition, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines).